# Ajaxurl return 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Im making a wordpress plugin which allows the admin delete a particular row in the database by clicking a button

```
<td>
    <img src="/DeleteRed.png" onclick="deleteRow(<?php echo $rowa->id?>)"><br>
</td>
```

Initially I was calling ajax like this

```
function deleteRow(val) {
    var url = "id="+val;
    alert (url);
    $.ajax( 
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:"../wp-content/plugins/salah-world/delete.php",
        data:url,
        success:function(data) {    
            console.log(data);
        }
     });
}
```

and using this PHP code

```
<?php
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); 
    require_once( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/wp-load.php');
    echo $id."ID";
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'iqamahTimes';
    $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->prefix . 'iqamahTimes' , array( 'id' => $id ) );
?>
```

Which was working fine, returning the id as well as deleting it from the database. But when I submitted my plugin Wordpress said calling wp-load.php is big no no. Which I understand why.

I then try using ajaxurl and came up with this for the ajax

```
function deleteRow(val) {
        var url = val;
        alert (url);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action':'exampleajaxrequest',
                'id'    : url
            },
            success:function(data)
            {    
                console.log(data);
                    //location.reload(true);
            }
        });

}
```

And the php is as followed

```
function exampleajaxrequest() {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    echo($id."id");
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'iqamahTimes';
    $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->prefix . 'iqamahTimes' , array( 'id' => '5' ) );
    die();
}
```

I have put the add_action under the construct method as followed

```
public function __construct(){
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_exampleajaxrequest', 'exampleajaxrequest' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_exampleajaxrequest', 'exampleajaxrequest' );

    add_action("admin_menu", array($this,"add_plugin_menu_fnbar"));
    add_action("admin_init", array($this,"register_dasettings"));

    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'register_admin_scripts'));
}
```

However when I run it I get this error 

**Warning**:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'exampleajaxrequest' not found or invalid function name in **/home/he/public_html/sd.org/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php** on line **525**
0

When I place the add_Action method somewhere else I just get 0 and nothing happens to the row.

NOTE: This is a backend script.

Comment: the code looks fine, the error would seem to suggest that function `exampleajaxrequest` is not defined, perhaps its in a file you forgot to include?

Comment: everything is in same file

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating here but is the function `exampleajaxrequest` actually a method within the plugin class?

If so you need to queue it up like  this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_exampleajaxrequest', array($this,'exampleajaxrequest') );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_exampleajaxrequest', array($this,'exampleajaxrequest') );
```

Comment: nope but get this error 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'fn_notibar_options' does not have a method 'exampleajaxrequest' in <b>/home/he/public_html/sd.org/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php</b> on line <b>525</b><br />
0

Comment: well that error would suggest that `exampleajaxrequest`  is in in fact not a method within `fn_notibar_options`, you need to have a closer look at where that function is defined and be sure the file is included when wp calls `do_action('wp_ajax_exampleajaxrequest')`;